# Default size in assembly code instructions

Tags: assembly, msp430

I have question about default size for assembly instructions in MSP430.

Say I have some made up code something like this :

```
push.w R10
push.w R11

mov.w 10(SP), R10
mov.w @R10+, R12

cmp #0, R12
inv R12
```

When I don't use .w with cmp and inv and others - does it default to .b in MSP430?

How will it influence the results?

I am new to all of this, so please bear with me.

Thank you.

Comment: You can use a disassembler to check what machine code your assembler chose to make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Section 3.4 of the [MSP430x2xx Family User's Guide](http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/slau144) says:

> All single-operand and dual-operand instructions can be byte or word instructions by using .B or .W
>   extensions. Byte instructions are used to access byte data or byte peripherals. Word instructions are used
>   to access word data or word peripherals. If no extension is used, the instruction is a word instruction.